# PHP: Quoting search result snippets from larger text

Tags: php, text-processing

Let's say I have a large block of text. I want a PHP routine or function to quote or summarise that text given a keyword. A bit like Google does, showing some sample quotes from the pages it finds.

eg

Large Text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam et magna ac vitae a. Donec libero
>   vestibulum dolor dapibus, etiam semper vitae, vel luctus nisl dui
>   metus sem. Mi vitae et elit, risus ultrices, ut **justo** est aenean
>   ultrices feugiat porttitor, vitae lectus. Posuere tempus, eleifend
>   lacinia ac eros nam consectetuer etiam. Viverra est arcu nulla, in
>   velit ipsum rutrum laoreet imperdiet, a dolor nihil nunc non facilisi
>   elit, id sed dui nobis quis, dignissim curabitur. Eget ligula arcu
>   rhoncus rerum elit, amet vitae, ipsum nam volutpat, felis in sed porta
>   ut nulla. Risus neque aliquet, laoreet convallis dolor mollis.

Search Query:

> Keyword: **justo**
>
> Words To Show: 15

Result:

> Mi vitae et elit, risus ultrices, ut **justo** est aenean ultrices feugiat
>   porttitor...

Are there standard or commonly used routines for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a search server like [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) if you want to have a full-featured full text search capability.  It is not too difficult to setup and provides very fast searching capability.  In addition, it can give you context-sensitive snippets of your text based on search terms.